# GitHub Private Repository in (free) Organization, update 2020

Tags: git, github, repository

In the new GitHub [update in April 2020](https://github.blog/2020-04-14-github-is-now-free-for-teams/) for organization with free plan, private repositories now are available.

For these private repositories, can **all members in the organization** view the code? Or only creator and collaborators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Jan 2021: Yes, all members of the organization can view the code. In particular:

- All members can see the private repo and its source code.
- Owners/Creator of such repo can adjust the settings of that private repo.
- Outsiders cannot see the existence of the repo.